# How to identify 5 numbers within 5% of each other out of 6 consecutive numbers

Tags: c#

Using C# I have to:

Take an user entered number and decide if 5 out of 6 of these numbers are within 5% of each other. Also identify when it's impossible reach success before going to all 6 numbers. An example of this would be in the first 3 numbers... if 2 were not within 5% of each other, no use continuing.

I've tried taking in the first 2 numbers, into an array, and setting a Min and Max assuming they are within 5%. By the time I get to the 3rd and 4th numbers, which also can reset my Min and Max, it's turned into a bowl of spaghetti :)

Please help!

Comment: Does 6 consecutive numbers mean that the numbers are already in order?  This would make your question much easier.

Comment: Is it the case that for each of your five numbers, they must be within 5% of each of the other 4? Or that you can arrange them such that each is within 5% of its neighbors? Also, since percent difference is calculated as `(a-b)/a` (or `|(a-b)/a|`, depending on your use case), it's important to distinguish which number you're using as your basis.

Comment: When you say "each other", does it mean in 5 numbers, each number will be in 5% of any of other numbers?

Comment: I might use a List<int> rather than an array, that way you can keep adding numbers to the end of the list without resizing.  I might also use the "Sort" method to sort the list.

Comment: `turned into a bowl of spaghetti`... use a loop?

Comment: In this case, I have to determine a Max and Min within 5% by (Max - Min)/Min. Then see how many others fall between the Max and Min. Of course each newly added number can become a new Max or Min. Currently I'm using a complex object with some properties to help me keep score. Including a List<Runs> where Runs is an object containing properties like Counts (the number), isMax, isMin, isOutlier. Then I send this object through a spaghetti bowl of If/Else and loops. It's ugly.